# Excel Formula to Add Varying Amounts to Previous Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm hoping someone can help me with this formula:
I need to create a list of numbers like the list below – basically I need 11 added to the previous cell, unless the previous cell ends in “6”, then only 4 gets added to the previous cell, and then adding 11 continues until the next cell ending in "6"

```
123456111
123456122
123456133
123456144
123456155
123456166
123456170
123456181
123456192
123456203
123456214
123456225
123456236
123456240
123456251
123456262
123456273
123456284
123456295
123456306
123456310
123456321
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Put `123456111` in A1

Then, put

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="6",A1+4,A1+11)
```

in A2, then copy down